# dcos mesos dns is not resolving masters and leaders

Tags: mesos, terraform, dcos

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.I am struggling on this more than three days and I could not fix this.

I am configuring a DCOS installation with the guidance of https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/installing/custom/advanced/

But Unfortunately, my dcos's dns server is not working properly.

### 1)Below is the output of the nslookup command:

```
# nslookup leader.mesos
;; Warning: query response not set
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 198.51.100.1, trying next server
;; Warning: query response not set
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 198.51.100.2, trying next server
;; Warning: query response not set
Server:     198.51.100.3
Address:    198.51.100.3#53

** server can't find leader.mesos: SERVFAIL
```

### 2) Below is the output of /opt/mesosphere/etc/mesos-dns.json

```
{
  "zk": "zk://127.0.0.1:2181/mesos",
  "refreshSeconds": 30,
  "ttl": 60,
  "domain": "mesos",
  "port": 61053,
  "resolvers": ["172.31.0.2"],
  "timeout": 5,
  "listener": "0.0.0.0",
  "email": "root.mesos-dns.mesos",
  "IPSources": ["host", "netinfo"]
}
```

### 3) Below is the output of the journalctl -u dcos-mesos-dns -b

```
  19:29:50 Authentication failed: EOF
     ***19:29:51 Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:2181: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2181: getsockopt: connection refused***
     19:29:52 Connected to 127.0.0.1:2181
     19:29:52 Authenticated: id=98693002200481794, timeout=40000
    service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    service: Unit entered failed state.
    service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    7/09/20 19:30:14 generator.go:124: no master
    7/09/20 19:30:14 resolver.go:156: Warning: Error generating records: no master; keeping old DNS state
    7/09/20 19:30:14 main.go:80: master detection timed out after 30s
    service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
    NS: DNS based Service Discovery.
    DNS: DNS based Service Discovery...
     19:30:19 Connected to 127.0.0.1:2181
     19:30:19 Authenticated: id=98693008095641600, timeout=40000
    DNS: DNS based Service Discovery...
    service: Main process exited, ***code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT***
    service: Unit entered failed state.
    service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    NS: DNS based Service Discovery.
    DNS: DNS based Service Discovery...
     19:39:57 Connected to 127.0.0.1:2181
     19:39:57 Authenticated: id=98693008095641610, timeout=40000
    lines 170-207/207 (END)
```

Please ask if you need more logs...

Thank you very much!

Comment: I pinged some people responsible for Mesos DNS.

Answer (score 1):

I could able to fix this issue by following the latest version of the DCOS installation guidance: https://dcos.io/docs/1.10/installing/custom/advanced/

my genconf/config.yaml

```
---
bootstrap_url: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9090
cluster_name: 'ProjectName'
exhibitor_storage_backend: aws_s3
aws_access_key_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
s3_bucket: cp-v902
aws_region: us-east-1
exhibitor_explicit_keys: 'false'
s3_prefix: dcos
ip_detect_filename: genconf/ip-detect
dns_search: ec2.internal
master_discovery: master_http_loadbalancer
exhibitor_address: internal-osdc-123456789.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
num_masters: 1
resolvers:
- XXXX.XXX.XX.XX
```